# RegisterHelper does not work as expected in handlebars

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Newbie to `NodeJs` and `Handlebars`. I am passing array of values to view and have written below helper to decide whether to include `view all` action button or not based on length of `array`. If `length>1` I want to display `action button` else not. Below is what I've.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("arrLength", function(array) {
     console.log(array.length>1); //logs proper true or false
     return array.length>1;
}
```

In view I've it as below:

```
{{#arrLength this.nArray}}<a class="clear blue" style="float:right;" href="javascript:void(0);">View all</a>{{/arrLength}}
```

But in view it is not getting displayed even though length is > 1. Any idea what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. I needed to bind to the option, which is passed as parameter. Not sure though what is the significance.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("arrLength", function(array,options) {
   if(array.length>1)
        return options.fn(this);
   else
        return options.inverse(this);
}
```